# Using dplyr on local vs remote databases

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I'm trying to understand how to use `dplyr` on a remote database vs data stored in R. Namely, I'm unclear on what functions can be used to with `mutate()`. For example, this works just fine:

```
diamonds %>%
    select(color, cut, price) %>%
    mutate(
        newcol = paste0(cut, color)
)
```

However, if I try to use `paste()` on a remote database (that is too large to store locally) I get an error saying

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  function paste0()
```

That's one example, but I noticed a similar error when trying to use POSIXct dates and other functions from non-base R.

**My question**: Am I limited to only using very basic aggregating functions like are mentioned [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)? If not, how does one implement other functions (custom, additional libraries etc.) through dplyr on remote databases?

Comment: I think your assumption is correct - "*dplyr allows you to write R code that is automatically translated to SQL. The goal of dplyr is not to replace every SQL function with an R function: that would be difficult and error prone. Instead, dplyr only generates SELECT statements, the SQL you write most often as an analyst.*" - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html

Comment: I think you can do all the postgres functions. Going to your example with paste0, postgres doesn't have paste0 (afaik), but it does have `||` so you could use mutate(xy = x %||% y)` to get string concatenation. The ?translate_sql page mentions this example.

Answer (score 2):

yes, `dplyr` uses the `dbplyr` package for the SQL translations.  In it, we have to manually specify how each R command translates to that specific SQL syntax, so in some cases one function may work for one database and not for others.  I just checked the translation for PostgreSQL and it looks like we have a translation for `paste()` but not `paste0()`. In the meanwhile, you can also pass SQL commands inside `dplyr` verbs, for example, `mutate(m = strpos(field1, "search"))` will run the PostgreSQL `strpos` that is used to locate a string within a field.